# Unable to delete 3TB external EFI cold storage from MAC

Tags: hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, macbook, efi

I have an external WD 3TB , i used it for my hackintosh before, now i just want to delete everything  in there and use it for my PC desktop, however it does not let me erase the drive completely.

My attempts in trying to delete it still shows that 2.2TB is still used. 
This is what the drive looks like in terminal...

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data UNTITLED                3.0 TB     disk2s2
```

Screenshot of disk utlity
https://prnt.sc/sbzw64

Screenshot of terminal 
https://prnt.sc/sbzzc1

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: 1. Your 3TB EFI is 209 MB in your text. (the disk is large but the EFI is 209MB).    2) There is a very well known issue with FAT formatted disks limiting them to 2TiB (2.2TB) with 512k sectors and no workarounds.  I think that the last is your problem.

Comment: would it be possible to clean this out using any windows software ?

Comment: i tried formatting it to NTFS on windows desktop and i have 2794.20GB, i still see the EFI partition on windows

Comment: diskpart clean?